# Flutter Bar Chart with vertial title on top

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

**How Can I do Same to same like this ??**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to check out [Flutter Syncfusion Chart](https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_charts).
It's a nice package to create all sorts of charts, you can check out the [official documentation](https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_charts) to create column chart and create [annotation with the same package](https://help.syncfusion.com/flutter/cartesian-charts/annotations).